# If a row is empty, how do I copy/paste data from the row below it to populate the empty row?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with numerous blank rows, and I need to extract specific data from cells below each blank row to populate the blank one. I'm just not good enough yet at VBA to figure out how to do this complex set of steps, so thank you in advance, and sorry to the developers who don't like how to do this questions.

I've broken down the steps I need.

1. Determine if row is empty.
2. If true, copy text from column A of the row below the empty row.
3. Paste text into column A of the empty row.
4. Change last three digits of text to "XXX".
5. Continue until end of spreadsheet.

EDIT: Cells as they currently are:

[image: Current]

What I want them to look like:

[image: Future]

I'm trying to do this for every set, but there may be 2, 3, 4, or more groups of rows with a blank row above them. So the VBA needs to include all of the rows in that group.

Comment: What is the desired outcome if you have two adjacent empty rows?

Comment: There is other data in columns below those rows that I would apply the same script to, but with different inputs.

Comment: In other words, the entire row is empty, and I need to populate specific cells with data parsed from cells in the row immediately below the empty one. In some cases adding punctuation or substituting characters. It's a really complex function I know...

Comment: I understand that, I am asking what happens if you have two rows that follow each other *and* that are empty. Copying empty cells in empty cells will result in empty cells. [A good MCVE is always useful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It might be worthwhile to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55639612/edit) to provide sample data and expected outcome

Comment: If two empty rows follow each other, then the script is complete and should stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This sounds like what you want.  If your numbers are numeric you'll want to convert them to text before your try to take out digits.*

```
Sub dostuff()

For ir = 1 To 10000

   If (Cells(ir, 1).value = "" And Cells(ir + 1, 1).value = "") Then _
      Exit For 

   If (Cells(ir, 1).value = "") Then _
      Cells(ir, 1).value = _ 
          Mid(Format(Cells(ir + 1, 1).value,"00000000"),1,5) & "XXX"

 Next ir


 End Sub
```